# After installing ubuntu14.04 through USB drive on surface 3 ..then I restart the system it again take me to install screen

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb

After installing ubuntu14.04 through USB drive on surface 3 ..then I restart the system it again take me to install screen

Will you please give me step by step solution.

Comment: Just remove the USB media and try again. And if you just installed then you have nothing to loose. You may want to try again but this time install a newer release. Newer releases have better support for newer hardware.

Comment: I try to do above step but it does not work ...and I want to use specific 14.04 version of ubuntu...

Comment: Any setting that I  want to do before or after restart

Comment: If you want to use a release older than the hardware it's your prerogative (and your problem). The rest of your comments make no sense. I can't help you.

Comment: @sandeeep did it still show the install screen after you removed USB and rebooted? because that's technically impossible

Comment: @summet ; It does not show me  the same screen, when I remove the USB drive, but it show me  Boot setting screen ....such as TPM, Secure boot control, Device information, Configure Alternate system boot order...etc.